# Adding association vs adding custom foreign key column in sequelize node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i am learning `node js` and `sequelize` and is confused in a scenario.
First of all have a look at the model which i have defined.

```
class Car extends Sequelize.Model {
static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return super.init({
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,  
       },
        name:{ 
        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
        defaultValue:''
       },
        //CASE 1 == can define custom foreign column like this
        company_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: {
                   model: 'Company',
                  key: 'id',
               },
           allowNull: false,
      },  

      },
      {
       sequelize,
       tableName: 'Car'
      }
    );
  }


  //CASE 2 == can define association like this
  static associate(models) {
      this.myAssociation = this.belongsTo(models.Company);

  }

}
```

When i follow case 1 this add as an column in the `car` table and when i run case 2 then is adds automatically a column `ComapanyId` in table.However if i run both case 1 and case 2 then two columns are created.One custom and one created by association.But i am confused which is correct way to add foreign key constraint between two table.Kindly make my concept clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can indicate what field will be used as a foreign key in an association definition:

```
this.myAssociation = this.belongsTo(models.Company, { foreignKey: 'company_id' });
```

If you don't use the **sync** method to autocreate tables for your models then the CASE 1 is used in migrations indicating an other side of a foreign key and the CASE 2 is to work with associated models when you create/read/update/delete records in a DB via sequelize models.

Comment: So if i am using sync:true then i should follow only CASE 2 ?

Comment: Yes, the CASE 2 will be serving two purposes simultaneously.